# Accessing files outside of Isolated Storage in WP7 Mango

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is it possible for a WP7 Silverlight application to access files outside of it's isolated storage? I know an application can't access another application's isolated storage but would it be possible to access shared files ?

Comment: Yes and no. Details, details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can only access files from isolated storage. Calling methods like File.Open() results in a MethodAccessException.

If you want to share files over application boundries a simple solution would be to store them on a remote location (in the cloud or on a regular webserver) and let your application work with these files.

Comment: The exception to this is files in the devices MediaLibrary as they can be accessed by all apps.