# What is the easiest way to send a text file to the Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

1. Is it possible to access phone storage in WP7 Mango? I can see Adobe Reader is reading attachments saved from emails, can my program do it too?
2. Is is possible to open a file uploaded on SkyDrive?

I need to open a .txt file and then manipulate its strings.

Comment: Your title and body of the question don't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to access phone storage in WP7 Mango? I can see Adobe Reader is reading attachments saved from emails, can my program do it too?

No. Adobe had to get Microsoft's help ([blessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068729/associate-file-extension-with-app-in-wp7-1)) for that.

> Is is possible to open a file uploaded on SkyDrive?

The [Live SDK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shelly_guos_ms_blog/archive/2011/09/20/get-started-on-live-sdk-for-windows-phone.aspx) for Windows Phone 7 should get you started with that.

There is a [sample project on GitHub](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK/tree/master/Samples/WindowsPhone/LiveSDKSample) for working with and manipulating data on SkyDrive.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more answers to these already asked questions.

1. [Accessing files outside of Isolated Storage in WP7 Mango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494651/accessing-files-outside-of-isolated-storage-in-wp7-mango)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346450/download-file-from-skydrive